# What is the probability

Tags: probability

When treated with an antibiotic, there is a 96% that a dolphins will be cured of an ear infection. If 7 dolphins with ear infections are treated, what is the probability that exactly 4 are cured?

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you know about the [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)?

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be the probability of success, and therefore $1-p$ the probability of failure.

The probability of exactly $k$ successes in $n$ independent trials is 
$$\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}.$$

Answer (score 1):

By the binomial distribution formula the answer is $P(X=7)=\binom{7}{4}(.96)^{4}(1-.96)^3$

Answer (score 1):

This is a binomial distribution where the probability of success, $p = .96$, the number of trials, $n=7$ and the number of successes $k=4$. So the answer is:
$$
{7 \choose 4}.96^4.04^3 = .0019
$$